# Rails .html.erb - if, else statement not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement

I am trying to show something if a user has 'messages'

**views/messages/index.html.erb**

```
<% if @user.messages.any? %>
You have messages!
<% else %>
Sorry, you have no messages
<% end %>
```

**controllers/messages_controller.rb**

```
class MessagesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @user = current_user
    @messages = @user.messages
end
```

When I have this code implemented even though the user has no messages (as confirmed by rails console :

```
    user = User.find(1)
user.messages.any?
=> false
```

The message 'You have messages!' still appears

Also thought to add that the authentication is using the **devise** gem

Comment: Where is the "show there are leads" in your code?

Comment: @BenjaminTan Sorry, just a typo it should read 'You have messages!" even though there are no messages associated to that user

Comment: You have a typo in your code - `@user.messsages` should be `@user.messages`. And are you logged in as user ID 1?

Comment: @sevenseacat The typo was when I was entering the code into SO, I've fixed it in the code above. Yep, I'm logged in as the user id 1. I've even created a new user and gone into the messages html page and still the same issue

Comment: Why don't you put your code on GitHub. Looks like a simple issue and something very minor is being missed out. COuld be the current_user helper.

Comment: @SatyaKalluri the authentication is using devise gem

Comment: @sevenseacat are there any more files that would be helpful that you think I should put up?

Answer (score 1):

```
<% if @user.messages.any? %>
  <%= "User with id #{@user.id} has messages" %>
<% else %>
  <%= "User with id #{@user.id} doesnt have messages" %>
<% end %>
```

This will show something like
  `User with id 5 has messages`
  or
  `User with id 6 doesnt have messages`

Now verify this from rails console

```
User.find(5).messages.any?
```

Comment: I tried this and it still shows that the 'User with id 2 has messages' even though when I run the console it shows => false to the User.find(2).messages.any?

Answer (score 0):

try

```
   <% if @user.present? %>
   <%= puts "User is selected" %> 
   <% if @user.messages.present? %>
   <%= puts "User have message" %> 
   <% end %>
   <% end %>
```